# Comparing dimension after intersecting with a hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let ${\mathfrak{p}}$ be a homogeneous prime ideal in $S = k[x_0, \dotsc, x_n]$ so that $x_i \not\in {\mathfrak{p}}$ and consider $H$ be the hyperplane $H = Z(x_i) \subseteq {\mathbb{P}}^n$. From Projective dimension theorem it follows that 
$$
{\mathrm{dim}}Z({\mathfrak{p}}) \cap H \geq {\mathrm{dim}}Z({\mathfrak{p}}) - 1
$$

I am trying to argue that they must be equal. If this is not true then ${\mathrm{dim}}Z({\mathfrak{p}}) \cap H = {\mathrm{dim}}Z({\mathfrak{p}})$. I don't see how $Z({\mathfrak{p}}) \not\subseteq H$ helps here.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the dimension of a proper closed subset $X\subset Y$ where $Y$ is irreducible and finite dimensional?

Comment: @Kreiser: Thanks. It just follows from the definition of dimension as $Z({\mathfrak{p}})$ is irreducible. I hate it when I ask something and the answer is trivial. :)

Comment: I made a downvote by mistake. It cannot be undone it seems.